# What permissions are required to read a sub directories size?

Tags: permissions

For example

```
du -hs /path/to/directory
```

Is it possible for a user to determine to size of /directory but not have read permissions for /path/to

Answer (score 1):

No, you will get a permission denied if the user is not allowed to read the directory. Example:

```
~$ du -hs tmp/
8,0K    tmp/
:~$ sudo chmod 000 tmp
:~$ ls -ltr
total 16
d--------- 2 rinzwind rinzwind 4096 dec  2 17:55 tmp
$ du -hs tmp/
du: cannot read directory 'tmp/': Permission denied
4,0K    tmp/
```

A user does NOT need read access to the file itself.

```
$ cd tmp/
:~/tmp$ ls -ltr
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 54 dec  2 17:55 1
:~/tmp$ sudo chmod 000 1
:~/tmp$ cd ..
:~$ du -hs tmp/
8,0K    tmp/
```

Comment: hmm is there any work around aside from moving the directory in question to the root directory. Would symbolic link would have the same permission problem?